# Most efficient way to perform an SQL-Statement containing a max-aggregate in the sub-query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a currency table and an exchange_rate_log table. The latter contains over a billion of records. The exchange_rate_log table contains the traded exchange rates for many currencies for the last couple of years.

Now I have to select for all available currencies (in the table currency) the latest valid traded exchange rate for a given exchange_currency and a given date.

So if the given exchange_currency would be "EUR" and the date would be yesterday. The result would return the latest trades of all available currencies into "EUR" in the time window from the first available entries in the table "exchange_rate_log" until yesterday.

The following query shows a possible way to get the answer. However the given query does not perform very well.

```
SELECT cur.name, log.price, log.valid_at
FROM currency cur
JOIN exchange_rate_log log ON (cur.id = log.currency_id)
WHERE log.valid_at = (SELECT max(log2.valid_at) 
                  FROM exchange_rate_log log2 
                  WHERE log2.currency_id = cur.id 
                  AND log2.exchange_currency = ?
                  AND log2.valid_at < ?);
```

Is there a possibility to get the same result with an adapted query which would perform better? Is it possible to create an index to boost the performance of the above query?

Remark: The target dbms is Oracle.

Comment: Check if you DBMS supports Windowed Aggregate Functions, here you need RANK (or ROW_NUMBER)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't tag which DBMS you're using, so this is using RANK from Standard SQL:

```
select *
from 
 (
   SELECT cur.name, log.price, log.valid_at,
       RANK()
       OVER (PARTITION BY cur.id
             order by valid_at DESC) as rnk
   FROM currency cur
   JOIN exchange_rate_log log on (cur.id = log.currency_id)
   WHERE log.exchange_currency = ?
     AND log.valid_at < ?
) dt
where rnk = 1;
```

If this is more efficient depends on the optimizing capabilities of the DBMS.

Otherwise adding a `log.valid_at < ?` condition to your original query might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1
    cur.name, log.price, log.valid_at
FROM exchange_rate_log log
INNER JOIN currency cur
ON log.currency_id = cur.id
WHERE log.exchange_currency = ?
AND log.valid_at < ?
ORDER BY log.valid DESC;
```

It is also very important to have an index on log.valid and log.exchange_currency or else nothing is going to make your query fast.

I also think that the performance of the query presented will be similar but I think that it is slightly simplified.

Comment: I think your query would not return the same result as the query of my example, as your query would just return one row.

Note: I have indexes on log.valid and log.exchange_curreny to boost the query :-)

Comment: You are right. If you are using MSSQL always run the actual execution plan to see what is going on. If you get table or index scans then you know you are in trouble.